# How to "do loop" with a filtered range - VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I have a macro which loops on a selected filtered range of cells and do some stuff only for the selected cells.

At this time, the loop is with For Next, with a message box to ask the user if he wants to continue (Yes/No).
I would like to change the loop method with a Do While with a messagebox including 3 choices (Previous, Next, Quit) instead of 2 choices (Yes, No).
In this new loop, I would use a counter related to cell line position in filtered range and do something like :

```
   Case Previous : Counter = Counter - 1
   Case Next : Counter = Counter + 1
   Case Quit : Exit For
```

The issue I am facing is that I do not know how to proceed easily with a counter, as my For Next loop does not currently have any counter, and as a referencing to cell position for a filtered range is not easy.

Any suggestion on how to proceed ?

Thanks !

```
Sub newstuff()
    Dim Msg, Style, Title, Help, Ctxt, Response, MyString
    Msg = "Do you want to continue ?"    ' Define message.
    Style = vbYesNo + vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2    ' Define buttons.
    Title = "MsgBox Demonstration"    ' Define title.
    Help = "DEMO.HLP"    ' Define Help file.
    Ctxt = 1000    ' Define topic
        ' context.
        ' Display message.
    Dim addr As String
    addr = Selection.Address 'Select a range of filtered cells in a column

    Dim cl As Range, rng As Range

    Set rng = Range(addr)

    For Each cl In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        Debug.Print cl 'Do some stuff for each cell of the filtered range
    Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title, Help, Ctxt)

        If Response = vbNo Then    ' User chose No.
          Exit For
        End If
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Comment: So you're going to use `MsgBox "Message", vbYesNoCancel` or will you be creating a `userform`?

Answer (score 0):

I’ll try working with something like (adding userform)

```
t=2

Do until t > rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).rows.count
Userform1.Show
‘Do something depending on button clicked on userform

t = t + 1

Loop
```